# How to use a for range loop to iterate through two lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, function, loops

Need some help please using the for loop with range and len. Two questions.

Say I have one list consisting of either "W' or a 'L's meaning a game won or game lost, and a second list with integers representing points scored (and the positions correspond to the same game), then how could I write a function (without using the zip function) that would tell a user for example 'how many games did we win and score exactly 3 points'?
And 'how many games did we win with at least 9 points'?

At first I tried merging the two lists and the positions, ie- position 0 would have a value of something like L4. Then I could search for the specific criteria, but this gets tricky when searching for points greater or less than a specific number (win with at least x points).

Now I'm thinking of iterating through one loop like i in for i in range(x)) and len. But I'm confused how this would work with both lists.

## my code is a disaster....

```
def score_check(lst1, lst2):
    for 'W' in range(lst1[i] if 3 in lst2[i]):
    .........
    .....
    return result 
    
def main():
    record = ['L', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'W']
    points = [4, 1, 3, 2, 7, 4, 3, 10, 8, 14, 7, 6, 7]

    check = score_check(record, points)
    print(check)

main()
```

Expected results:

```
2 wins with 3 points scored and
2 wins with at least 9 points scored
```

Comment: Loop over the range, use the index?

Comment: you can even use a dictionary to store records and points. Each game will be associated with a list such as game1 : [record1, points1]  where game1 is the key and [record1, points1] is the value. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: I don't know why you're using python if you're going to limit yourself to not using it's built in features that make the language so useful. Using zip here is almost a no brainer. Also I agree with @satya using a dict would make much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to use `zip`. But, as you don't want to use that, you can do:

```
def score_check(lst1, lst2):
    lst_size_1 = len(lst1)
    lst_size_2 = len(lst2)
    if (lst_size_1 !=lst_size_2):
        return

    for i in range(lst_size):
        print (lst1[i])
        print (lst2[i])
```

Comment: I'm working through an online assignment that's focusing on the fundamentals and it says the only list function I can use is Len, no zip. Still confused though

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `zip` then you can just use the index of the elements.

```
record = ['L', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'W']
points = [4, 1, 3, 2, 7, 4, 3, 10, 8, 14, 7, 6, 7]

combined = [{'points': points[i], 'result': record[i]} for i in range(len(record))]

# this way is cleaner
#combined = [{'points': p, 'result': r} for r, p in zip(record, points)]
```

Now `combined` is a list of dictionaries containing key/value pairs for the `record` and points `entries` in your original lists. It assumes both lists are the same length, but this seems a reasonable assumption otherwise your data is not really valid. `zip` would handle this seamlessly by stopping when it exhausts the shorter of the two lists. This code would throw if it tried to access a non existent index in either list.

If you want to now query this list, you can just use the `filter` built-in function and pass it a predicate to decide what is in the results and what is not.

example

```
print('matches where score was greater than 3')
for result in filter(lambda r: r['points'] > 3, combined):
    print(result)
```

This includes any entries with a points value larger than 3. You could just as easily make it `<` (less than), `>=` (great than or equal) or `==` (equal to) any number you want.

You can also combine the result parameter into what is filtered on

```
print('matches where score was less than 5 but won')
for result in filter(lambda r: r['points'] < 5 and r['result'] == 'W', combined):
    print(result)
```

Note: that the filter function is always linear (O(n)). They always run over all the entries. So for larger sets of results its inefficient and slow. One way to tweak it would be to sort your list by score and use binary searches (in python the `bisect` module) to narrow your search. This would only have an impact if you were searching based on scores. If you wanted to search on W/L result then you're back to linear.

Answer (score 0):

So zip is not allowed. What about list comprehension:

```
def score_check(results, points):
    wins = [points[i] for i, v in enumerate(results) if v == 'W']
    exactly_three = len([win for win in wins if win == 3])
    at_least_nine = len([win for win in wins if win >= 9])

    return (f'{exactly_three} wins with 3 points scored',
            f'{at_least_nine} wins with at least 9 points scored')

record = ['L', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'W']
points = [4, 1, 3, 2, 7, 4, 3, 10, 8, 14, 7, 6, 7]

print(*score_check(record, points), sep='\n')

2 wins with 3 points scored
2 wins with at least 9 points scored
```

When function parameters are two lists only then to get desired output text and conditions must be hardcoded and this is not optimal usage of function.